# Cannot connect zte android device

Tags: android

I have ZTE Cool android phone, which I want to use it for android development. I could not see the device from Eclipse. I could not install the some drivers for Windows 7.

When I the connect phone to a PC, Windows says that the driver installation is being done, but  it does not finish successfully. It says *"ZTE HSUSB device did not install successfully"*. When I try to download and install the driver manually, it says the driver is up to date. So I could not connect to device from Eclipse.

Can anyone help solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the phone driver from ZTE websit